# CreateObject("ADODB.Command") - Run-time error '429': ActiveX component can't create object

Tags: vba, ms-access, ado

I have an old Access solution that includes opening a connection and inserting some lines in a SQL database.  I had to make a very small change that had nothing to do with that connection.  After the change I compacted the database.

The solution works normally for me, but the person that normally runs it is getting the Run-time error I outlined in the subject.  I had another user try and also got this error.  It seems I am now the only one that can run this, yet I did nothing to the code or the access db as a whole that I can see explaining this.

The button they press that triggers the error:

- Sets a variable as ADODB.Connection
- Defines the connection string
- ERROR TIME:  Then it runs a function that executes a stored procedure using that connection.  The error point is showing as occurring at the top of that function, when it attempts to CreateObject("ADODB.Command").

Run-time error '429': ActiveX component can't create object

Can anyone offer anything as to why this user that could work with it suddenly can't despite the same security, same machine, etc.

Comment: Sounds like you're missing the ADO library reference in this Access solution, or the client computer is missing the needed library.

Comment: Always helps to show your actual code.  If it's able to create an ADODB connection then it may not be a library/reference problem

Comment: Can you try to use early binding? Is the reference to *Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects*  available?

Answer (score 0):

Sigh... Thanks for the responses.  It turns out to be our security software and the fact that I moved the solution to a different location.  Out of sight out of mind.  I forget that I have some exemptions setup for myself, so I didn't see how it could be that.  I just need to learn to check that stuff first.